# How to detect if the value of a property in an JSON Model is changed with a given value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a given json model named "**entities**" for example:

```
var entities =
[{"name":"Test1","isDirty":false},
{"name":"Test2","isDirty":false},
{"name":"Test3","isDirty":true}]
```

I need to show the list below by using ng-show when there is an object with isDirty is TRUE detected using the model **entities** the code below doesn't work. I'm only using this element once and not repeatedly.

```
<li ng-show="entities[isDirty:true]">Click <span class="red">'View Errors'</span> to finalize results.</li>
```

I'm using the latest library of AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a function that check isDirty

```
$scope.checkDirties = function() {
var length = $scope.entities.length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
if ($scope.entities[i].isDirty) return true;
}
return false;
};
```

And use

ng-show="checkDirties()"

Comment: I have code like this however, I need this to be run everytime and remotely show the <li> whenever there is a isDirty property set to true..

Comment: You don't need to watch or digest.
The simplest way is to use $rootScope
Put entities array into $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following as well.

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-show="entry[$index].isDirty"></li>
</ul>
```

So when you do this, whenever something changes in entries object it will render accordingly on UI. Do make sure you define entries object on $scope.

Comment: The list element is only used once. I'm only using it for the display.. I need to know how to watch a particular model with a property then automatically show/hide that list<li> element using ng-show or other approach